# How to use If statement in map function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using the `map` function to assign and populate table names only if `object['Size/ scale of support'].` is equal to a data that I'm passing using props. I've seemed to have got the logic right but the `map` is not allowing me to use my `if` statement. Is there a way I can use an `if` statement on my map function?

```
    updateData(result) {
        const data = result.data;
        console.log(data);
        let new_data = []
        data.map(
            (object) => {

                if (object['Size/ scale of support'].toLowerCase() === this.props.data.toLowerCase()) {
                    console.log("support",object['Size/ scale of support'])
                new_data.push(
                    {
                        scale_of_support : object['Size/ scale of support'],
                        size_of_funding_instrument : object['Size of funding instrument'],
                        maturity_of_innovation_candidate : object['Maturity of innovation/ candidate'],
                        maturity_of_innovation_innovator : object['Maturity of innovation/ innovator'],
                        web_and_profile : object['Web and profile'],
                        source_of_information : object['Source of information'],
                        funding_instrument_name : object['Funding instrument name'],



                    }
                )
                }
            }
        )

        this.setState({ cvs: new_data });

       
    }
```

Comment: The point of `.map()` is to transform the contents of an existing array into a new array. If you're going to build a new array with your own code, don't use `.map()`, use `.forEach()` instead.

Comment: What does *"not allowing me to use my if statement"* mean? How does it stop you from using `if` inside `map`? Also, why use `.map` here, you need a `for` loop or `forEach`.

Comment: Either use `let new_data = data.map(...).filter(item => !!item)` or use `reduce` to create a new array.

Comment: What do you mean *"not allowing me to use my if statement"*? Unless you're using typescript, this code will not throw an error. It's not the proper way to use `map`, but it's not an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works:

```
var foo = [1,2,3];
foo.map(item => {
    if (item === 2) console.log(item * 2);
    return item;
});
```

which proves that your code is correct. If you use Typescript/Lint, then you may encounter errors because of this. If that's the case, you have several options to solve it:

## Refactor

You can refactor your code, write a function that performs the conditional and its operation and only call that function from inside `map`.

## Ternary operator

You may use the ternary operator as well, like:

```
mycondition ? myFunction() : myOtherValue;
```

Comment: This answer fails to warn the OP about the use of `map` for side effects. Obviously that's a good way to gain acceptance and upvotes, because it requires the least amount of work, but it also opens potential answer seekers to logic errors and continued abuse of language features.

Comment: map creates a copy of the array, having the same number of elements in the destination array, but its items are transformed in comparison to their original counterparts via the function passed to map. It's a read-only operation from the perspective of the array. forEach traverses the array. I consider neither to be superior in comparison to the other. They are both helpful and useful and the preference - if rationally determined - depends on the actual use-case.